# PHP reads only first 8 characters from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a MySQL table which contains Unicode  Malayalam strings. While reading the table using PHP, only the first 8 characters are stored / read in the fetched array.

Although the full string is present in the field the balance parts are not stored in the array. The field is string Varchar(50).
By default the database character set is set to utf8mb4.
PHP Code is as follows:

```
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die ();

    $db=mysql_select_db("drivingtest",$con);    //connects database
    mysql_set_charset('utf8mb4',$con);
    $query1="select * from dt_mst where quest_no != ".$row." ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
    $result=mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo trim($row[2]);
```

shows only the fist 8 characters of the string

Comment: What is your PHP code to do this? No one is going to be able to help you effectively unless you post what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

I think your string was escaped in entities having 6 characters. For example, code with 8 characters:

```
ഇതു ഒരു നല്ല
```

Escaped into code of 50+ characters:

```
&#3335;&#3364;&#3393; &#3346;&#3376;&#3393; &#3368;
```

View into your database. Check that your database is created with utf8 character set. If it is not, run this command:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Also in PHP set utf8 mysql connection before any select queries:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'");
```

See also useful link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-conversion.html

Comment: If you really need to use `mysql_*` use [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/mysql-set-charset) and not `SET NAMES`.

Comment: $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die ("Hey loser, check your server connection.");
 
  
 $db=mysql_select_db("drivingtest",$con); //connects database
    mysql_set_charset('utf8mb4',$con);
 $query1="select * from dt_mst ;
 $result=mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo trim($row[2])." ";